Client Web Socket Getting Aborted After Successful Connection In MAUI C#
This is the code behind of the one of the content page of my MAUI chat application.
private ClientWebSocket _clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
private readonly Uri _serverUri = new Uri("ws://10.0.2.2:6969/chat");

public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ConnectToServer();
}

private async void ConnectToServer()
{
    try
    {
        if (_clientWebSocket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            _clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
            await _clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(_serverUri, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        _ = Task.Run(ReceiveMessages);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private async Task ReceiveMessages()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    while (_clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        WebSocketReceiveResult result;
        var message = new StringBuilder();

        do
        {
            result = await _clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                message.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count));
            }
        }
        while (!result.EndOfMessage);

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            chatMessages.Children.Add(new Label { Text = message.ToString() });
        });
    }
}

private async void SendMessage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (_clientWebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            var message = edInputMessage.Text;
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            await _clientWebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                chatMessages.Children.Add(new Label { Text = $"Me: {message}" });
            });

            edInputMessage.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

In constructor 'public MyPage()', I am calling 'ConnectToServer' method. Which makes the connection with websocket server. This function successfully connects the client with websocket. In this function 'ConnectToServer', I am getting client web socket connection state as 'Open'.
After initializing page & page loaded, I am clicking the button from UI. Which calls the event 'SendMessage_Clicked'. THis event will send the message by using the soccket. But, Here I am getting the client websocket connection state as 'Aborted'.
I can't figure out what's happening there. Need help to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

What platform did you test on?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Android.

You can refer to the workaround in this case: .NET WebSockets forcibly closed despite keep-alive and activity on the connection.
Workaround1: add System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = int.MaxValue in public MyPage(){}. Workaround2: try the code: _clientWebSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;

In the second workaround, this eliminates the problem of the websocket closing when the timeout is reached. However, it may also completely shut down the sending of ping messages.
